# How to make div/popup to show once in the browser. Plain vanilla script

Tags: javascript, html

// JavaScript Document

I am trying to do when the user goes to the browser it only shows up once. I know it is something to do with local storage but all I see is jquery when I search something similar.

I really want to know how to do it in plain javascript no jquery.

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    console.log("SEAF Fired");  

    function popup (hideOrshow){
        if (hideOrshow == 'hide') 
        document.getElementById("popupBox").style.display="none";
        else document.getElementById("popupBox").style.display="block";
    }

    window.onload = function (){
        setTimeout(function(){
            popup('show');
        },3000);

        document.getElementById('close').onclick=function(){
            document.getElementById('popupBox').style.display="none"
        };          
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

More about local/ session storage is here;
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

I'd encourage you to use session storage rather than the local storage.

**Why?**

window.localStorage - stores data with no expiration date

window.sessionStorage - stores data for one session (data is lost when the browser tab is closed)

Assuming that your browser supports local storage, and you handle the case otherwise.

```
if (!window.sessionStorage.popupFlag) {
   // Logic to show popup once goes here...
   window.sessionStorage.popupFlag = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Cookie` to do this. I've override value of `hideOrshow` in `popup` method by using `Cookie` functionality. If once show the popup and cookie is set then popup will not show next time.

Please check below code:

```
(function() {
        "use strict";
        console.log("SEAF Fired");  

        function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
                var d = new Date();
                d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
                document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
        }

        function getCookie(cname) {
                var name = cname + "=";
                var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
                var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
                for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
                        var c = ca[i];
                        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                                c = c.substring(1);
                        }
                        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                        }
                }
                return "";
        }

        function popup (hideOrshow){
                hideOrshow = getCookie("hideOrshow");
                if(hideOrshow == ""){
                    hideOrshow = "hide";
                    setCookie("hideOrshow", hideOrshow, 365);
                }
                if (hideOrshow == 'hide') 
                document.getElementById("popupBox").style.display="none";
                else document.getElementById("popupBox").style.display="block";
        }

        window.onload = function (){
                setTimeout(function(){
                        popup('show');
                },3000);

                document.getElementById('close').onclick=function(){
                        document.getElementById('popupBox').style.display="none"
                };          
        }
})();
```

Comment: it works! im just wondering how to reset the cookies ...lol i try to delete cookies in my browser but apparently it doesn't show. even if i try it to different broswers still doesn't shw

Comment: To reset cookie, you should set expire you cookie. Example: `setCookie("hideOrshow", hideOrshow, -1);`